# How to read a flat formatted text file where the contents are in chunks and separated by special chars

Tags: python

How to read a flat text file containing information in chunks separated by some special characters? As in the example below, each block of contents end with "EC" and "\".

Is there any inbuilt function that can read such files in chunk?

I can do C style programming by reading each line at a time but I guess there must be some inbuilt function to look for special character and store the values into some array or other data structure.

```
sfshf
sjgks
sghk
sghk
EC
\\
hdkhg
djgldkdh
dhg
dh
dhjdhlj
dhjl
EC
\\
hdj
dhjl
dhjl
dhjldhjldjkhl dlhjd dhjl
dhl dhjl dhjl
EC
\\
```

Comment: How do you want to store the data in Python? List of lists?

Comment: list of lists is okay as I have to perform some other functions of each of these text blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work for you to use `split()`?

`fulltext = open('myfile').read()
components = fulltext.split('EC\n\\\\\n')`

`components` would then be an array of elements between your EC\\ blocks

This of course is provided your file doesn't contain anything else.

Comment: Okay thanks. Works fine except that the second line will be `components = fulltext.split('EC\n\\\\\n')`

Comment: Ah my bad.  Edited it into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read line-by-line (or byte-by-byte) until you hit your stop sequence, there's no way around that.

You can, however, write a helper function to yield the chunks you need.  It's marginally easier to do this one byte at a time, since your stop sequence spans two lines.

```
def reader(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        c = f.read(1)
        out = []
        while len(c) > 0:
            out.append(c)
            if out[-6:] == ['E', 'C', '\n', '\\', '\\', '\n']:
                yield ''.join(out).splitlines()
                out = []
            c = f.read(1)
```

demo:

```
list(reader('test'))
Out[24]: 
[['sfshf', 'sjgks', 'sghk', 'sghk', 'EC', '\\\\'],
 ['hdkhg', 'djgldkdh', 'dhg', 'dh', 'dhjdhlj', 'dhjl', 'EC', '\\\\'],
 ['hdj',
  'dhjl',
  'dhjl',
  'dhjldhjldjkhl dlhjd dhjl',
  'dhl dhjl dhjl',
  'EC',
  '\\\\']]
```

This is minimal in memory footprint (it only reads as much of the file into memory as necessary to reach the next stop sequence) but is not going to be blazingly fast due to looping `append` calls for each character in your file.  But it's best not to prematurely optimize - this is fast enough for 95% of people.  If not, well, it's time to dig in with `itertools` to speed it up.